# What does "not number % 5" means? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

As per question. I know that it does the same thing as `number % 5 == 0`, but I don't understand it. Can anyone kindly give an explanation for it?

Comment: What have you tried to answer your own question? Python is an interpreted language. Start at the interpreter and type some stuff in. Start with `number = 23` (or whatever), then type `number % 5`. Then type `not number % 5` etc. See if you can noodle it out. Also check out tutorials on '%' and 'boolean logic'.

Comment: I think its just personal taste. On my machine its marginally faster by 15% but that sort of thing is easily lost in the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Any number other than `0` is `True` so say `3%5 = 3` which is `True` and `not True` is `False`. So the only time it can be `True` is if `number % 5 == False or 0` because `not False` is `True`.

or

```
number % 5 == 0  =  False == False = True
not(number % 5)  =  not False      = True
```

If that doesn't make sense I can try to explain it another way.